# Github action to firebase hosting cd preview

Tags: firebase, yaml, github-actions

I am setting up my first svelte project with vite and it should be hosted on firebase. I made a action that deploys to firebase, that works just fine. However i made a similar github action that generates a preview channel on pull request that is not working.

This is my code.

```
name: Deploy to Preview Channel

on:
  pull_request_target:
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build

      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SVELTE_WETHER_SITE }}"
          expires: 10d
          projectId: your-Firebase-project-ID
```

and this is the error i get

```
Run FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
/home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:3759
                const error = new RequestError(message, status, {
                              ^

RequestError [HttpError]: Resource not accessible by integration
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:3759:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async createCheck (/home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:5680:17)
    at async run (/home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:11435:14) {
  status: 403,
```

i have tryed to use both
on:
pull_request_target:
and
on:
pull_request:
as i read somewhere that the secret might not have acces to the key otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs due to the restrictions on read/write permission for workflows. Follow these steps to solve this.

1. Go to your repository Settings
2. Click Actions and then click General
3. Scroll to Workflow Permission Section
4. Mark the 'Read and Write Permissions'

[image: Workflow Permissions]

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent so many hours trying to figure it out