# How to deploy preview to Firebase Hosting using a GitHub action on a PR in an organization's private repository?

Tags: github-actions, firebase-hosting, cicd

I've set up Firebase Hosting for a private repository on GitHub, and deployed to the live channel using the [FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy) action template. This was an easy task to accomplish, just letting Firebase and a service worker reach my organization is enough to set it up.

This initial set up automatically created the `FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_(project name)` action secret, so no problems here. The issue is when we try to automatically deploy to a preview channel, both action files are relatively the same, they use the same action template. The sheer difference is when and where from it's called. After reading through [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-check-run), I guessed the issue was in the privileges Firebase service worker has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a checklist:

- Make sure that the action uses `'on': pull_request_target`. Also, this may allow malicious 3rd parties to access resources/execute code so please read this [blog post](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/)
- Set "Workflow permissions" to "Read and write permissions" under **Organization settings > Actions > General**.

Hopefully you'll get the automatic deployments up and running after this.

---

Resources

1. [Github action to firebase hosting cd preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75782966/github-action-to-firebase-hosting-cd-preview)
2. [Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR faild in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862219/deploy-to-firebase-hosting-on-pr-faild-in-github-actions)
3. https://github.blog/changelog/2021-02-19-github-actions-workflows-triggered-by-dependabot-prs-will-run-with-read-only-permissions/